# Web scraping data from a different webpage that is specific to the title

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

records = []
keep_looping = True 
url = 'https://reelgood.com/source/netflix'
while keep_looping:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    title = soup.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'cM'})
    for t in title:
        movie = t.find(attrs={'class':'cI'}).text
        year = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').text
        rating = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').text
        score = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').text
        rottenTomatoe = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').text
        episodes = t.find(attrs={'class':'c0'}).text[:3]
        records.append([movie, year, rating, score, rottenTomatoe, episodes])
    
    url_tag = soup.find('a',attrs={'class':'eH'})
    
    if not url_tag:
        keep_looping = False
    else:
        url = "https://www.reelgood.com" + url_tag.get('href')
```

The above code gets me all the data from this webpage: https://reelgood.com/source/netflix

I want this data and then i want to scrape additional data about each movie, which seems to be stored specifically for each movie. This is what the url looks like where i want to get the data from:

https://reelgood.com/movie/thor-ragnarok-2017

(As you can see, it adds the movie title to the url), but i want to get this data for every movie. The data i want to scrape from this webpage is the genre (action & adventure, comedy, ect).

Any thoughts on how i can achieve this?

Thank you for your help, as this is my first solo project web scraping, so if this is common knowledge i will learn from here.

Comment: For some reason, the URL for the movies doesn't load for me. It doesn't really matter though, why can't you scrape each movie page the way you have done for the list page?

Comment: i have not been successful with finding the specific class i need to use to do so. I will keep looking, but in the inspects could you help me with where i need to specifically go to find the class? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can find the urls from the main film listing, and then iterate over each to find the additional information that can not be found in the `html` table on the first page:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from typing import NamedTuple
class Movie(NamedTuple):
   year:int
   name:str
   imdb_rating:str
   rotten_tomatoes_rating:str
   tags:list
   age:str
   description:str

start = soup(requests.get('https://reelgood.com/source/netflix').text, 'html.parser')
links = [f"https://reelgood.com{i['href']}" for i in start.find_all('a') if re.findall('^/movie/', i['href'])]
new_results = [soup(requests.get(i).text, 'html.parser') for i in links]
extra = iter(filter(lambda x:re.findall('^\d+$', x), [i.text for i in start.find_all('td')]))
tags = [['h1', {'itemprop':'name'}, True], ['div', {'class':'eC'}, True], ['div', {'class':'eD'}, True], ['a', {'class':'eA'}, False], ['span', {'title':'Maturity rating'}, True], ['p', {'itemprop':'description'}, True]]
final_results = [[(lambda x:[getattr(h, 'text','N/A') for h in x] if isinstance(x, list) else getattr(x, 'text', 'N/A'))(getattr(b, ['find_all', 'find'][method])(tag, c)) for tag, c, method in tags] for b in new_results]
d = [Movie(*[int(next(extra)), *i]) for i in final_results]
```

Output:

```
[Movie(year=2017, name='Thor: Ragnarok', imdb_rating='7.9/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='92%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description='Thor is on the other side of the universe and finds himself in a race against time to get back to Asgard to stop Ragnarok, the prophecy of destruction to his homeworld and the end of Asgardian civilization, at the hands of an all-powerful new threat, the ruthless Hela.'), Movie(year=2010, name='Thor: Ragnarok', imdb_rating='7.9/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='92%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description='Thor is on the other side of the universe and finds himself in a race against time to get back to Asgard to stop Ragnarok, the prophecy of destruction to his homeworld and the end of Asgardian civilization, at the hands of an all-powerful new threat, the ruthless Hela.'), Movie(year=2017, name='Coco', imdb_rating='8.5/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='97%', tags=['Animation', 'Action & Adventure', 'Music'], age='7+', description="Despite his family’s baffling generations-old ban on music, Miguel dreams of becoming an accomplished musician like his idol, Ernesto de la Cruz. Desperate to prove his talent, Miguel finds himself in the stunning and colorful Land of the Dead following a mysterious chain of events. Along the way, he meets charming trickster Hector, and together, they set off on an extraordinary journey to unlock the real story behind Miguel's family history."), Movie(year=2015, name='Coco', imdb_rating='8.5/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='97%', tags=['Animation', 'Action & Adventure', 'Music'], age='7+', description="Despite his family’s baffling generations-old ban on music, Miguel dreams of becoming an accomplished musician like his idol, Ernesto de la Cruz. Desperate to prove his talent, Miguel finds himself in the stunning and colorful Land of the Dead following a mysterious chain of events. Along the way, he meets charming trickster Hector, and together, they set off on an extraordinary journey to unlock the real story behind Miguel's family history."), Movie(year=1999, name='Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2', imdb_rating='7.7/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='83%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Space', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description="The Guardians must fight to keep their newfound family together as they unravel the mysteries of Peter Quill's true parentage."), Movie(year=2014, name='Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2', imdb_rating='7.7/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='83%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Space', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description="The Guardians must fight to keep their newfound family together as they unravel the mysteries of Peter Quill's true parentage."), Movie(year=2005, name='Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales', imdb_rating='6.6/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='30%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Ghost', 'Sequel'], age='13+', description="Thrust into an all-new adventure, a down-on-his-luck Capt. Jack Sparrow feels the winds of ill-fortune blowing even more strongly when deadly ghost sailors led by his old nemesis, the evil Capt. Salazar, escape from the Devil's Triangle. Jack's only hope of survival lies in seeking out the legendary Trident of Poseidon, but to find it, he must forge an uneasy alliance with a brilliant and beautiful astronomer and a headstrong young man in the British navy."), Movie(year=1999, name='Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales', imdb_rating='6.6/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='30%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Ghost', 'Sequel'], age='13+', description="Thrust into an all-new adventure, a down-on-his-luck Capt. Jack Sparrow feels the winds of ill-fortune blowing even more strongly when deadly ghost sailors led by his old nemesis, the evil Capt. Salazar, escape from the Devil's Triangle. Jack's only hope of survival lies in seeking out the legendary Trident of Poseidon, but to find it, he must forge an uneasy alliance with a brilliant and beautiful astronomer and a headstrong young man in the British navy."), Movie(year=2005, name='Captain America: Civil War', imdb_rating='7.8/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='91%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero', 'War'], age='13+', description='Following the events of Age of Ultron, the collective governments of the world pass an act designed to regulate all superhuman activity. This polarizes opinion amongst the Avengers, causing two factions to side with Iron Man or Captain America, which causes an epic battle between former allies.'), Movie(year=2017, name='Captain America: Civil War', imdb_rating='7.8/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='91%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero', 'War'], age='13+', description='Following the events of Age of Ultron, the collective governments of the world pass an act designed to regulate all superhuman activity. This polarizes opinion amongst the Avengers, causing two factions to side with Iron Man or Captain America, which causes an epic battle between former allies.'), Movie(year=1994, name='Doctor Strange', imdb_rating='7.5/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='89%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Doctor', 'Magic', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description='After his career is destroyed, a brilliant but arrogant surgeon gets a new lease on life when a sorcerer takes him under his wing and trains him to defend the world against evil.'), Movie(year=2017, name='Doctor Strange', imdb_rating='7.5/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='89%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Doctor', 'Magic', 'Superhero'], age='13+', description='After his career is destroyed, a brilliant but arrogant surgeon gets a new lease on life when a sorcerer takes him under his wing and trains him to defend the world against evil.'), Movie(year=2012, name="Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest", imdb_rating='7.3/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='54%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Monster'], age='13+', description='Captain Jack Sparrow works his way out of a blood debt with the ghostly Davey Jones, he also attempts to avoid eternal damnation.'), Movie(year=2013, name="Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest", imdb_rating='7.3/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='54%', tags=['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Monster'], age='13+', description='Captain Jack Sparrow works his way out of a blood debt with the ghostly Davey Jones, he also attempts to avoid eternal damnation.'), Movie(year=2013, name='The Imitation Game', imdb_rating='8/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='90%', tags=['Biography', 'Gay & Lesbian', 'Biography', 'World War II'], age='13+', description="Based on the real life story of legendary cryptanalyst Alan Turing, the film portrays the nail-biting race against time by Turing and his brilliant team of code-breakers at Britain's top-secret Government Code and Cypher School at Bletchley Park, during the darkest days of World War II."), Movie(year=1974, name='The Imitation Game', imdb_rating='8/10', rotten_tomatoes_rating='90%', tags=['Biography', 'Gay & Lesbian', 'Biography', 'World War II'], age='13+', description="Based on the real life story of legendary cryptanalyst Alan Turing, the film portrays the nail-biting race against time by Turing and his brilliant team of code-breakers at Britain's top-secret Government Code and Cypher School at Bletchley Park, during the darkest days of World War II.")]
```

Now, it is possible to find the tags associated with each film:

```
print([i.tags for i in d])
```

Output:

```
[['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero'], ['Animation', 'Action & Adventure', 'Music'], ['Animation', 'Action & Adventure', 'Music'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Space', 'Superhero'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Space', 'Superhero'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Ghost', 'Sequel'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Ghost', 'Sequel'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero', 'War'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Science-Fiction', 'Based on Comic', 'Sequel', 'Superhero', 'War'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Doctor', 'Magic', 'Superhero'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Based on Comic', 'Doctor', 'Magic', 'Superhero'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Monster'], ['Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy', 'Monster'], ['Biography', 'Gay & Lesbian', 'Biography', 'World War II'], ['Biography', 'Gay & Lesbian', 'Biography', 'World War II']]
```

Comment: it looks good. i will have to mess around with this and make it my own. thanks again.